# Is it possible to create a calculation field between two datasets in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have two datasets. One consists of shipments and the other for demands.

I would like to have the difference between the shipment quantity that is sent to particular countries and the demand for these particular counties.  and then subtract the sum of the demands for particular countries.
The two datasets don't have a common key. So I am wondering if it is possible to do that via a calculation field.

Thank you

Comment: If there is no common key, you will not be able to join two datasets - just like in every database. Couldn't you use the countries as a common key? Supply more information about your datasets.

Answer (score 2):

You said it yourself - if there is no common key, how would you tell it to join the tables together?

You could create a "key" by creating two tables and aggregate them to country-level and use the country as a key. An easy way to join the two datasets could be to:

```
1) Create a worksheet and aggregate 'Shipment quantity' to country level

2) Mark everything and copy paste (Ctrl + C, Ctrl + V)

3) Tableau will now insert the newly created dataset on a new worksheet.

4) Do step 1-3 again with 'Demand' instead

5) In Data-sources you can now link these two together with 'Country' as a key.
```